# How to perform math on an array's values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with the following value:

```
2, *, 5
```

How can I execute this string like so:

```
2 * 5
```

so the result returned is 10?

Comment: What about parentheses and order of operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most horribly insecure way possible would be to do something like this:

`eval([2,"*",5].join(''))`

But I could never recommend doing that, like ever. The "right" way to do it would be to write some kind of parser.

```
var ops = [2,"*",5]

var val = ops.shift();
while(ops.length > 0) {
    var item = ops.shift();
    switch(item) {
        case "*": val *= ops.shift();
        case "+": val += ops.shift();
        case "-": val -= ops.shift();
        case "/": val /= ops.shift();
    }
}
```

This would essentially work like a very simple calculator... but I still couldn't really recommend this approach.

What are you trying to do exactly? Maybe there is a better way to model what you are trying to do other than an array?

Comment: That's really nice, as in, I like this.

Comment: @32bitkid that's what I'm trying to do, build a simple calculator. Could you please give an example of what can be done that makes using eval directly insecure?

Comment: Insecure in the sense that it executes javascript without checking it first... if the array you passed in was something like [4,"*","2;","doSomething();",8] it would return 8 (like you would expect it to), but it wouldn't do exactly what you thought it did (and it this case execute a method called doSomething).

So you just have to be careful when using eval(), that you know exactly what you are evaluating. If you are trying to make a simple calculator, then I would expand more on the second approach. You can validate your user input before operating on it.

Comment: google for "Code injection" for more info about the nature of the exploit

Comment: There's way too much hype about eval security that the general public seems to think it's always evil.  Eval only has security liabilities if you allow unfiltered input from a remote user.  If you filter the input appropriately, then there is nothing wrong with eval and, in many cases, even unfiltered input used locally can do nothing more than people running scriptlets or greasemonkey scripts can already do on their own browser.  One should be aware of where the dangers are, but not throw the baby out with the bath water.  Sometimes eval is very useful and safe.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree with what you are saying, if handled correctly its fine. In other areas, it can be much more damaging. JavaScript is probably the least nasty place to use the exploit. But I still stand by my warning and suggest one uses it with care.

Comment: FYI, the non-eval solution in this answer does not support operator precedence, or parens or many other operators the same way that `eval()` does.  If it's only ever two operands and these four operators, then this is fine - otherwise there's a lot more work to do to replace `eval()`.

Comment: @jfriend I know, that's why i said a "very simple calculator" :)

Comment: Just pointing that out for the benefit of the OP.  I happen to think that an eval solution with appropriate precautions is a better solution here and a lot more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can handle your own precedence using order and parentheses, and you are okay with using `eval`, then use `eval`:

```
var str = "2,*,5";
var exp = str.split(",").join("");
var n = eval(exp);
alert(n);
```

Also, that assumes that you have no spaces in your initial string.

Comment: Tell the OP to first test `exp` against `/[0-9+\-*/()]/` for the +1 :-)  Also the OP started with the array so the initial split is unncessary.

Comment: When using *eval*, spaces have the same importance as in any expression. In this case, they are more or less irrelevant.

Comment: @RobG - good point. Ray toal, shouldn't there be a % in there?

Comment: Sure, @karim79, a percent for modulo is good, and perhaps a decimal point, too.  Depends on how much the OP wants.  One could even go nuts on the sanitization and write validator code for things a regex cannot do....

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
var array = [2, '*', 5];
eval(array.join(''));
```

This is one of the few things *eval* is useful for, however you likely don't want to give it just anything.